# UITableView weird separator line color

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitableview

i have a problem in setting UITableViewCell background color. I wanna change it into my own color, so I use this code to change that background color :

```
UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] init];

    bg.backgroundColor = [ColorManager backgroundInput];
    bg.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bg];
```

I implement this code in CellForRowAtIndexPath method.

The weird thing I have is, when i tap into a cell, the separator line color being highlight just like the image below. I just wanna make it still dark, anybody have idea?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Do you tell about that line on top of cell?

Answer (score 1):

After setting up your own background view,which will have the line or not,
you can clear the default tableview color

```
tablename.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

OR

If you don't want to remove the default line then you can give same color of background view to line color

//You can specify the RGB of background view

```
tablename.separatorColor =     [UIColor colorWithRed:R green:G blue:B alpha:1.0f];
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
Objective-c
tablename.separatorColor = [UIColor blackColor];

Swift
 tablename.separatorColor = UIColor.blackColor();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is

```
[tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set the `backgroundColor` of the `UITableViewCell` to a clear color.

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```